# URL rewrite redirect issue

Tags: mod-rewrite, isapi

I rewrite all URLs to lowercase, and it works fine.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [CL,R=301]
```

But there are few places where IDs used and IDs transform to this:

Original URI pattern (spaces are added to highlight replacement):

7f4320a7-9b13-4439-837f-ba0dbbed29ad **%2C** b3a990ae-b693-4496-b7cc-59f0b1cfc14a

Localhost:

7f4320a7-9b13-4439-837f-ba0dbbed29ad **,** b3a990ae-b693-4496-b7cc-59f0b1cfc14a

Dev server:

7f4320a7-9b13-4439-837f-ba0dbbed29ad **%252c** b3a990ae-b693-4496-b7cc-59f0b1cfc14a

I don't quite understand why it differs, apparently 0x2C is HEX for comma, but I have no idea how and why it transforms.

I use `!(pattern Repeats in every ID using URL)` as a temporary solution, but I'm curious what's wrong with it and can I use a condition that ignores HEX values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comes out I needed an to add [NE] (noencode) to `RewriteRule (.*) $1 [CL,NE,R=301]`.

%25 is a '%', so characters were encoded twice.